# Delay in between uart packets sent from another device to PC using FTDI chip

Tags: serial-port, usb, uart, ftdi

I have a device sending a series of 20 byte UART frames ( 20 bytes each without delay in between the 20 bytes).By sending data from device to PC Using **FTDI chip TTL to USB converto**r , there is a delay of **16 ms** in between the 20 bytes sometimes.Why is it so?

This was monitored on - **Look RS232** software

When observed on a monitoring software in PC there is a delay of 16ms -in between the 20 bytes in some of the frames. eg 4 bytes first then 16 and so on.Or 6 bytes first then the rest 10 after 16 ms.
It has been tried with different baud rates.The same issue persists.

I read that there is a latency timeout in FTDI chip if minimum 64 bytes are not received and this latency is 16ms. But this should not affect my application since the maximum length at which data is sent continuously is 20 bytes after which there is a delay and then the next 20 byte arrives. So as soon as the 20 bytes are received then time out should occur. There should not be a delay in between.
Reference:
https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_107_AdvancedDriverOptions_AN_000073.pdf

Could this be due to USB scheduling delay and the fact that it it not exactly interrupt driven? does anybody have a possible solution for this? the delay is always 16 ms.

Expected result is 20 bytes data without delay in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without delay will be impossible. As we are talking about USB there is always some jitter due to the nature of USB and most bus systems in general. The latency/timeout setting of the FT driver is typically set to 16 ms. You can change that under windows in the device manager via the settings dialog of the corresponding virtual com port. Best I could get with a FT2232H with baud rate beyond 10 MBps is 1.46+-0.31 ms (n=1000 packages) for packets traveling back and forth.

Comment: Thanks... For the reply... But I would like to know what exactly causes the delay. I did try changing latency time in the com port settings. But the delay is still 16ms. I think the latency time should not affect it since I sent only 20 bytes at a time. For the ftdi chip it is mentioned that latency time is the time taken for ' time out' to occur if data bulk less than 64 bytes (or the size set-multiple of 64) is received. I hope my interpretation is correct. A packet sent from pc through ftdi chip to ttl and observed on logic analyser does not have this delay!

Comment: I am curious how you "monitor" the delay for a packet sent from the PC. Because one would need an independent, delay-"free" trigger signal path to compare it to the speed of the USB interface. 
And just to make sure that we are on the same page: I was talking about the "BM Options: Latency Timer" (if I remember correctly). Setting this to 1 does not change the behaviour at all? How do you open/address the port? Via the VCP or the D2XX driver?

Comment: Sorry I did not monitor the usb data coming from the PC. I monitored the USB converted to TTL-UART frame from PC on a CRO & analyser which is delay free , monitored the packets with the exact time. For the data I received from the ftdi chip to PC I just monitored it on software lookrs232-https://www.lookrs232.com/ . Tried to change latency in the  COM port in device manager. There was a difference in the pattern after setting it to 1ms. Still the delay bw  is 16 ms. I hope I'am correct it saying that the latency time is not an issue if the frame is less than 64 bytes long??

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the algorihm at work is similiar to TCPs Nagle: it tries to combine small burst into larger USB packages to avoid "flooding" the BUS with small segmented packets. So only sends/receives smaller than 64 bytes should be affected. If reduction of the latency and timeouts settings do not solve the issue for you I would recommend to try longer packets and/or higher send rates to identify the issue. Maybe try a different software for addressing as well (e.g. putty or python or arduinos monitor or ...) although it should not make a difference at all.

Comment: Thank you fo the suggestion. Shall try with longer packets and monitor on other software.

Comment: No.... Delay in bw data block when sending 4 blocks of 62 byte data With a gap of 30 ms  after each. Also with 80 bytes. There is no delay like before. In this situation when the block size is changed to 64 from 4k the 80 bytes gets split with 16ms latency time-as expected. Probably it is the issue with small frame size. Thank you very much.

Comment: depending on your usecase you could consider using the D2XX driver. It is tougher to use but allow higher level of control.

Comment: Another issue has popped up..... When I try to send 62 bytes. I send a frame of 62 bytes every 60 ms. But on the USB side in the application code(written by another person in c#) it is received as  2 or more 62 byte frames clubbed together after a few minutes of running. It should be received as one 62 byte frame every 60 ms. But on the third party software look rs232 no such issue is there.